# Does drawRect change intrinsic content size?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an `UIView` which implements a custom intrinsic content size and occasionally changes its size. The view is positioned relatively to its superview using a set of constraints (leading/trailing etc.)

I know that whenever I modify the data that the `UIView` uses to determine its size, I need to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` on the view to trigger a re-layout.

However, I'm wondering if there's any relationship between `drawRect` and view layout i.e. does `drawRect` cause the intrinsic content size to change and/or invalidate it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 steps before view is getting onto the screen:

1) update constraints step
 2) layout step
 3) drawing step

So, where is the intrinsic content size in these steps? When view updates constraints it looks into intrinsic content size to set non required constraint to its size. Every time you call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize(), the view understands that it should change these constraints according to new data in update constraints step in the next update cycle.

Then, in the second step the view sets frames, according to all constraints added. It not looking into intrinsic content size, it only sees size constraints that was added.

In the third step, the view is even not wondering if you using autolayout or not. In this step all frames are already calculated. And view is only drawing in its frame.

So, the answer on your question is NO. These methods cannot call each other directly. How big the view will be drawn sometimes depends on intrinsic content size. But in drawing process, intrinsic content size cannot be changed.